# Connection Refused when Deploying Ruby on Rails application on Ubuntu Server

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, capistrano, connection-refused

I'm pretty new to the DevOps world so I believe it is likely I'm missing something simple or not looking in the right places.

I have deployed a Ruby on Rails application to an Ubuntu Server (on Linode).  To complete the deployment I use Capistrano 3, Nginx, and Puma.  From what I can tell the deployment is entirely successful.  There are no errors in the Puma, Nginx, or Rails logs.  Puma is running. However, when I try to access the site via a web browser I get a Connection Refused error.

I'm not sure if it's port related, but running `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` outputs this, which to my knowledge is correct:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29940/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1038/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1036/postgres       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30456/puma 4.3.7 (t 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29940/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      29940/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      1318/java           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9200                :::*                    LISTEN      1318/java           
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      1318/java           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9300                :::*                    LISTEN      1318/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1038/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      1036/postgres
```

Running `sudo ufw status numbered` outputs this:

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 80,443/tcp                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 22,80,443/tcp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 4] 22,80,443/tcp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Let me know if I should add any configuration files. What would cause the connection to be refused?